# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT function won't return expected output

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL instance on Google Cloud SQL, version: 5.5.49-log

The following query does not return the expected result

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.x) as group_concatted
FROM (
    SELECT 'a' AS x
    UNION
    SELECT 'b' AS x
) AS t
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have an problem due to value of **group_concat_max_len** (by default it's 1024) property here is the doc on how to increase value for it https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-flags

Comment: No, that was not the case. "a,b" requires 3 bytes, so 1024 is more than enough. I had to give up using Cloud SQL and install MySQL on the instance itself as a workaround.